# Warnings "use @jridgewell/sourcemap-codec instead" and "deprecated rimraf" after global installation of NestJS 9.2

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-config

I installed NestJS (v. 9.2) globally and received the following warnings:

```
npm i -g @nestjs/cli
npm WARN deprecated sourcemap-codec@1.4.8: Please use @jridgewell/sourcemap-codec instead
npm WARN deprecated rimraf@4.1.2: Please upgrade to 4.3.1 or higher to fix a potentially damaging issue regarding symbolic link following.

nest --version
9.2.0
```

Is it what I can fix myself or will the NestJS developers fix this in the next release? I have no idea how to replace or upgrade this myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

rimraf is a direct dependency of `@nestjs/cli` and there [is already a pull request to update it](https://github.com/nestjs/nest-cli/pull/1952) so there's nothing you need to do there.

`sourcemap-codec` is a dependency of `magic-string` which is a dep of `@angular-devkit/schematics` which is a dep of `@nestjs/schematics` which is a direct dep of `@nestjs/cli`. [Looks like it already uses the newer package on version 0.30.0](https://github.com/Rich-Harris/magic-string/blob/master/package.json#L63), which [the newest `@angular-devkit/schematics`](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/main/packages/angular_devkit/schematics/package.json#L18) is already using, and there is a PR in both [`@nestjs/cli`](https://github.com/nestjs/nest-cli/pull/1935) and [`@nestjs/scheamtics`](https://github.com/nestjs/schematics/pull/1319) to update this, so again, nothing for you to do.